# Удаление элемента из множества по условию

Tags: python, python-3.x

Решаю задачу:
Удалите из `new_set` все элементы, которые меньше 34 или больше 120

```
new_set = {1, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 36, 37, 38, 39, 41, 42, 43, 44, 46, 47, 48, 49}
{new_set.discard(x) for x in new_set if x < 34 or x > 120}
print(new_set)
```

вот такую ошибку выдает:

```
RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration
```

подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new_set = {1, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 36, 37, 38, 39, 41, 42, 43, 44, 46, 47, 48, 49}
new_set = {x for x in new_set if x < 34 or x > 120}
print(new_set)
```

Comment: Код делает противоположное тому, что требовалось по условию в вопросе: не удаляет элементы < 34 или > 120, а оставляет только их. Условие нужно поменять на противоположное.

Comment: Правильное условие: `if 34 <= x <= 120`

Comment: @CrazyElf в вашем условии тоже опечатка. Тогда уж правильно будет `if 34 <= x >= 120`

Comment: @ZxNuClear Ну вы сами своё условие прочитайте. `x` больше или равно 32 и `x` больше или равно 120. Первая проверка получается просто лишняя )  Вы просто не умеете читать такие условия в питоне, видимо )

Comment: @CrazyElf ваша правда, проглядел :(

Comment: Ну, есть простое визуальное правило - скобки в одну сторону должны смотреть в таком "склеенном" условии, чтобы всё было хорошо, а если они смотрят в разные стороны, то что-то не то )

Comment: @CrazyElf, правда не знал о таком варианте написания условия, теперь буду знать )) полезно, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
new_set = {x for x in new_set if x > 34 if x < 120}
```

Comment: Пробовали запускать? Этот код синтаксически некорректен (буквально, выдаст ошибку синтаксиса)

Comment: @insolor, похоже на опечатку, но по крайней мере после замены второго `if` на `and` будет выполняться начальное условие, а не так как в принятом ответе.

Comment: @NowhereMan, может и так, но это нужно было явно добавить как пояснение, а не просто кидать одну строчку кода (при этом не проверив, корректна ли она).